# Does react-native-video work with react-native-navigation

Tags: android, video, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to get videos to play in my react native app. [I'm trying to use react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) but when running the app via `react-native run-android` I get the error message:

"undefined is not an object (evaluating'_reactNative.NativeModules.UIManager.RCT Video.Constants')

This message doesn't really tell me much, but after trying to get this to work for a while I started to suspect that [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), , which is the navigation I use for my app, has something to do with it. So I created a new react-native project and added react-native-video to it and got it working without too much trouble.

So my question is if anyone has experienced the same thing, and could provide a solution to getting these two packages working together?

My settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'newproj'
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')

include ':app'
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/')
```

build.gradle Module react-native-video

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
}
```

dependencies in build.grade Module: app

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactVideoPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

    @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
        // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And in my react native project:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

  <View style={styles.container}>
        <Video source={{uri: "youtube.com"}}  
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.player = ref
          }}   
resizeMode="cover"  
style={styles.backgroundVideo} 
/>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you please update your post with your code?

Comment: Not sure how it helps with this particular problem but I've updated with code now!

Comment: There is no connection between `react-navigation` and `react-native-video`, the `undefined is not an object ` usually occurs when you forgot to declare the param. So it would be helpful if you post the complete code of that particular screen(js code not the java code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createAdditionalReactPackages` should return the packages.

Change this

```
@Override
public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return null;
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
}
```